# How to define key property

Tags: actionscript-3

*how to define key property in actionscript3.0  I'm having a error named 'Access of Undifined property key'*

```
enter code here

var steps:Number = 5;
var spriteX:Number = 265;
var spriteY:Number = 265;
function checkKeys() {
if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
spriteX += steps;
} else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
spriteX -= steps;
}
}
function updatePawel() {
knight._x = spriteX;
knight._y = spriteY;
}
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
checkKeys();
updatePawel();
};
```

Comment: The code you posted is ActionScript 2, not ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 0):

your code is AS2. Set your target language to AS2, so the compiler won't throw AS3 syntax errors.

If you're using the Flash IDE, go to "Publish Settings", select the "Flash" tab, then change ActionScript 3.0 to ActionScript 2.0 as the target language.

I hope it helps,
Rob